# Match a list of words in a string with space inbetween characters

Tags: php, regex, words

Say that I have a string that looks like this:

> Give me your xw al l et now!

And a list of banned words:

> wallet, banana, potato

How would I write the regular expression to catch any of those words? Even with spaces inbetween characters.

Cheers.

Comment: What have you written so far? Please add code so we know what you're tried already and can modify it to suit your needs

Comment: This question is discussed in a very similar way here: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/63573/nicer-way-to-check-if-string-contains-all-words-from-an-array

Answer (score 1):

This code will do the work:

```
foreach($banned as $word) {
    $chars = str_split($word);
    $pattern = implode(' ?', $chars);
    $check = preg_match('/'.$pattern.'/i', $text);
}
```

$banned is the array of forbidden words

$text is the text you are validating for forbidden words

And $check marks if given banned word is found, and depending on your logic you want to achieve, use this variable in appropriate way for you.

Comment: But it will catch "a bit cheesy"  as "bitch"  and "smash it" as "shit" a.s.f.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. For more accurate check a more complex approach would be needed.

Answer (score -1):

Simple way to catch any word (without space) :

```
function censorship($bannedwords, $sentence) {
    foreach($bannedwords as $word) $sentence = str_replace($word, '****', $sentence);
    return $sentence;
}

$bannedwords = ['banana', 'potato'];
echo censorship($bannedwords, 'Every banana is a potato');
// Output : Every **** is a ****
```